# Created new Azure tenant (test org) and removed Authenticator account. Cannot log in no more

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

2 or 3 weeks ago I created a new Azure tenant in order to try out Azure B2C. I created a lot of stuff and made a PoC on B2C.

However, this morning my Microsoft Authenticator app didn't receive any notifications and I lost it because I had to finish some tasks. Nothing helped. After an hour I found no solution and removed all the accounts on the Authenticator. At the end our company Azure admin reset MFA and it was all working fine. But my newly created tenant won't let me log in even thought I can log in to my company tenant. According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant) and what I've seen myself, in the new tenant my Azure domain user was the admin. Hence I thought if the two-step verification works now, it should work in my custom tenant as well. The only thing I get in the Authenticator when I try to switch directory to my custom tenant is

"*Unable to process notifications from your work or school account. If this account has been removed from the app, please also remove it from the MFA registration page. Otherwise remove the account and re-add it.*"

Any suggestions on how to take control of my tenant is appreciated. Thx a bunch.

O.S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled out a support case with Microsoft Azure team and after they reviewed my situation via Microsoft Teams, the only solution was to reset MFA by Azure engineers. So the next day they did reset my MFA and from then on everything works nicely.

Comment: I guess the best practices is to create global admin account with a very strong password (15-20 chars) and login monitoring (so you are alerted if someone logs in from another place) but without MFA for that particular account. I just witnessed MFA not working for any reason prior company Azure admin reset it and in those cases you are still capable of working while waiting for MFA to work again.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, it seems like you have been locked out of your own custom tenant and can’t log in except MFA through Microsoft Authenticator app. Here are the following steps you can try to get access to your account: -

•   Try removing the Authenticator app and first try to configure the custom tenant in it. It should be configured.

•   Once the custom tenant is configured in the app, then try adding the company id in the authenticator app for MFA.

•   After adding the company id, make sure to reconfigure the MFA policy for your custom tenant to give options for two factor authentication to include text message and call verification.

•   To configure the above, log in to your azure tenant  Azure Active Directory  Security  Policies  Enable Microsoft Authenticator, Text Message, FIDO2 Security Key. Once, multiple authentication methods are enabled, go to Security again, MFA  Configure additional cloud-based MFA settings, a new window will open to configure verification options for sign in.

[image: MFA Options]
[image: MFA Configurations]
[image: Authentication methods]

•   In that, select all the options so that next time, in case such situation arises, you have an option of selecting the second verification method. Below are the screenshots for more reference.

•   Also, go to the authenticator app on your phone and select backup your credentials to a recovery account.

Please find the below link for reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-auth-app-backup-recovery

Thanking you,